# Multithreading: Confusion between the publisher thread and the subscriber thread

Tags: c#, mqtt, opc

I have created a Windows forms application which able to publish OPC tags into an MQTT broker, Now I'm trying to do the reverse, write MQTT tags into an OPC server. when I have started both the agent (the publisher) and the transfer (the subscriber) the two threads do the same work which is publishing I don't know what is the problem.
The start method is below :

```
public byte Start()
    {
        try
        {
            byte connectResult;
            if (IsLWT == false)
            {


                connectResult = this._MqttClient.Connect(ClientID, Username, Password, IsCleanSession, KeepAlivePeriode);
            }
            else
            {             
                   
                connectResult = this._MqttClient.Connect(ClientID, Username, Password, willRetain, willQos, true, willTopic, willMessage, IsCleanSession, KeepAlivePeriode);

            }

            // 0 means that the connection suceeded
            if (connectResult == 0)
            {
                this.Rate = GetRateFromOPCGroups();
                this._publisherThread = new Thread(() => Publish());
                this._publisherThread.IsBackground = true;
                this._publisherThread.Start();
                IsStarted = true;
            }

            if (connectResult == 0)
            {
              //this.Rate = GetRateFromOPCGroups();
                this._SubscriberThread = new Thread(() => Subscribe(topics));
                this._SubscriberThread.IsBackground = true;
                this._SubscriberThread.Start();
                IsStarted = true;
            }

            return connectResult;

        }
        catch (IntegrationObjects.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttClientException ex)
        {
            MQTTServiceLogger.TraceLog(MessageType.Error, MQTTServiceMessages.startAgentFailed(this.Name,ex.Message));
            return 11;
        }
        
        catch (IntegrationObjects.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttCommunicationException ex)
        {
            MQTTServiceLogger.TraceLog(MessageType.Error, MQTTServiceMessages.startAgentFailed(this.Name, ex.Message));
            return 11;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MQTTServiceLogger.TraceLog(MessageType.Error, MQTTServiceMessages.startAgentFailed(this.Name, ex.Message));
            return 11;
        }
    }
```

1.This is the publish code:
private void Publish()
{

```
        while (true)
        {
            if (IsStarted)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (_MqttClient.IsConnected)
                    {
                        isConnected = true;
                        if (this.OPCItems.Count != 0)
                        {

                            JsonMQTTMessage JsonMessage = new JsonMQTTMessage();
                            JsonMessage.Timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
                            JsonMessage.ListofValues = new List<UpdatedOPCItem>();

                          
                        
                            lock (lockOPCItems)
                            {
                                foreach (OPCItem Item in OPCItems.ToList())
                                {
                                    if (Item != null)
                                    {
                                        UpdatedOPCItem upItem = new UpdatedOPCItem();
                                        upItem.ID = Item.ItemID;
                                        upItem.value = Item.ItemCurrentValue;
                                        upItem.quality = Item.ItemQuality;
                                        upItem.timestamp = Item.ItemTimeStamp.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
                                        upItem.DataType = Item.ItemDataType;
                                        JsonMessage.ListofValues.Add(upItem);
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                           
                            var messageTopublish = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonMessage);
                            ushort res = _MqttClient.Publish(Topic, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageTopublish), Qos, Retain);
                            ResetValues();
                            Thread.Sleep(Rate);
```

2. This is the Subscribe code:

public void Subscribe(List topics)
{

```
        while (true)
        {
            if (IsStarted)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (_MqttClient.IsConnected)
                    {
                        isConnected = true;
                        foreach (string topic in topics)
                        {
                            ushort msggId = _MqttClient.Subscribe(new string[] { $"{ topic }" },

                           new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE });
                        }
                        Thread.Sleep(Rate);

                    }
                    else
```

Comment: For one: is that intentional that you only have one `IsStarted` for both? Second: Please add `Publish()` and `Subscribe(topics)` implementations.

Comment: What does "IsLWT" represent?

Comment: `while (true)  {  if (IsStarted)` - that's a bad idea, but probably not your problem. How do you confirm they both "do the same work"?

Comment: When I clicked at the start button of the subscriber (Transfer) and check by another MQTT Client I saw new messages are published in the MQTT broker. the same work when I click at the start button of the publisher(Agent).

Comment: So? The same code behaves the same: great! That doesn't mean both _Threads_ do the same work. I'd expect them both to subscribe _and_ publish.

Comment: If you do not want this kind of confusion, write two different methods, that do two different things. As is, you have one method, that does two things (actually much more than 2). Not a good idea. Especially if it doesn't work the way you think it should. Make it as easy for you to understand what's happening. Understanding the code is more important than having "as less code as possible".

Comment: Both Threads publish messages. I want one publish message and the other subscribe get these messages and write then in an opc server.

Comment: I have already two methods as you can see Publish and Subscribe(topics) method .

Comment: Which you both are executing. Always.

Comment: Do you mean that I should have two methods to start the two threads? StartPublisher() and StartSubscriber() ?

Comment: That would be a good start, yes.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to resolve the problem in this way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have created two methods one for the publisher and the other for the subscriber but I still have the same problem. PS: I'm using the same class MQTTAgent for the subscriber and the publisher it means both are MQTTAgents